# Accessing a UIView's parent UIViewController using the UIResponder chain

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3

I recently found [a static C function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39886134/2415822) on Stack Overflow which returns a `UIViewController` reference from a containing subview using the responder chain:

> ```
> static UIViewController *viewControllerForView(UIView *view) {
>     UIResponder *responder = view;
>     do {
>         responder = [responder nextResponder];
>     }
>     while (responder && ![responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]);
>     return (UIViewController *)responder;
> }
> ```

I wanted to write this in Swift 3 as a programming exercise.  My first pass looked like this:

```
func viewController(forView view: UIView) -> UIViewController? {

    var responder = view as? UIResponder

    while (responder != nil) {
        if let viewController = responder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }

    return nil
}
```

Then I tried using a `repeat while` loop, to see if the structure would look any better:

```
func viewController(forView view: UIView) -> UIViewController? {

    var responder: UIResponder? = view

    repeat {
        responder = responder?.next
        if let vc = responder as? UIViewController {
            return vc
        }
    } while responder != nil

    return nil
}
```

I'm really not a fan of the `while responder != nil`.  Is there a way I can loop while checking if the responder is a `UIViewController`?  Maybe I can make this a recursive function by making the parameter a generic `UIResponder` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and there is nothing wrong with checking if an optional is `nil` unless you actually need the value if it is not.

Here is an example where the comparison to nil is inappropriate:

```
if someOptional != nil {
 doSomethingWith(someOptional!)
}
```

This of course should be written as

```
if let something = someOptional {
  doSomethingWith(something)
}
```

But in your case there is nothing wrong with the check.

A recursive version would also require the check for `nil`, but it could be written using an `if let` statement. But this version would have to take a responder as parameter:

```
func viewController(responder: UIResponder) -> UIViewController? {
    if let vc = responder as? UIViewController {
        return vc
    }

    if let next = responder.next {
        return viewController(responder: next)
    }

    return nil
}
```

A more elegant way to express this would be a calculated property in an extension on UIResponder:

```
extension UIResponder {
    var viewController: UIViewController? {
        if let vc = self as? UIViewController {
            return vc
        }

        return next?.viewController
    }
}
```

Here the explicit check for nil can be eliminated thanks to optional chaining.

I would prefer your repeat/while solution though. But in the end it is a matter of taste.

The performance of the recursive version will be worse unless the compiler can do tail call elimination there. I am not sure if it will be able to do so. But this should hardly matter. If you get to a situation where this is a bottleneck you have worse problems.

Comment: You can make your recursive solution even more elegant using the nil-coalescing operator: `return self as? UIViewController ?? next?.viewController`